# Можно ли использовать calc() в медазапросе?

Tags: css

Есть такой медиазапрос:

```
@media screen and (max-width: calc((100vh - 389px) * 1.715))
```

Корректно ли использовать calc() в медиазапросе?

Пишут, что его испоользовать нельзя, но в браузере все корректно отрабатывает.

Comment: _Пишут, что его испоользовать нельзя_ - кто пишет?

Comment: Например здесь - https://peterwilson.cc/media-queries-calc/

Comment: Этой статье уже 9 лет, читайте что-нибудь поновее

Comment: А в чём смысл вычислять ширину экрана на основе высоты вьюпорта?

Comment: смысл есть, это не простой сайт, а одноэкранный промосайт

Comment: судя по всему это поддерживается в последних версиях почти всех браузеров: [CSS at-rule: @media: calc() expressions](https://caniuse.com/?search=calc%20media). Начало поддержки судя по всему 2018 год, поэтому во время написания статьи выше - это вполне могло не работать.